# How to use ng-bind with document.addEventListener() in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, keypress, ng-bind

I have to make hotkay for my page on AngularJS. I use

> document.addEventListener()

Method keyDownTextField() sets value wordToShow:

```
export class listenKey {

    constructor() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => this.keyDownTextField(e), false);
    }

    keyDownTextField(e: any) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        this.logKey(keyCode);

        this.wordToShow = "Hello world!";
    }

    logKey(key: any) {
        console.log( key );
    }
}
```

There is the template:

```
<div ng-click="$ctrl.logKey()" ng-bind="$ctrl.wordToShow"></div>
```

The problem is: ng-bind works when the div is clicked but don't works when addEventListener registers that the key is pressed. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS doesn't know to trigger digest cycle on event listener callback.

You can wrap `this.keyDownTextField(e)` in a timeout:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => $timeout(() => this.keyDownTextField(e), 0), false);
```

Don't forget to inject `$timeout` service!

Alternatively, you can also call `$scope.$apply` after `this.wordToShow = "Hello world!";` in `keyDownTextField(e: any)`. Don't forget to inject `$scope`!

You may also want to check AngularJS built in ng-keypress ([ngKeyPress](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)).